# Google App Engine Standard Python3 app still serving old files, even if all versions deleted

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

My deployments were all working fine during development then all of a sudden, without me changing anything Google stopped serving new files and stuck to a version.

I tried deleting all versions except the last one:
[image]

I tried clearing memcache

It tried versions->diagnose->source to look at the code directly on StackDriver, which could not be simpler:
[image]

I tried clearing browser cache and opening the url on a different computer

And still loading up the url serves the old content, like if it was cached somewhere.

if I use https://[VERSION].[APPID].appspot.com then it serves the last version. But only using https://[APPID].appspot.com serves the old version from yesterday that is not anywhere anymore.

What happened Google??

Comment: Your content is being cached somewhere? Where? One tool is `curl` Look at the headers for one of your objects. That might give you a clue. `curl -i URL`. Use the available tools to analyze the problem instead of guessing.

Comment: Try Chrome, use the debugger. When loading your page, look at the network traffic. Is Chrome actually making a request for new data or is the request cached?

Comment: Do you get a `307 Internal Redirect` when visiting the page? There's a similar thread in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137881410) that had been solved. To summarize, if this issue is not reproducible in an incognito window, which disables extensions by default, the issue could be caused by a certain extension and would have to disable that extension. I invite you to read through the thread as it goes more in-depth regarding the issue

Answer (score 0):

The only surefire technique I have found to bust all caching for Google App Engine is to change the [`base URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) for each new version of the app.

## app.yaml example

In this example, the `base href` rotates from `b0, b1, ... b9` and then back to `b0`. However, this is arbitrary, as long as you aren't repeating `base hrefs` more than once every couple of weeks.

```
runtime: python37
service: default

handlers:
- url: /b3/(.*\.(html|htm|map|js))$
  static_files: b3/\1
  upload: b3/.*\.(html|htm|map|js)$
  secure: always

- url: /b3/assets/
  static_dir: b3/assets
  secure: always
```

## index.html example using Flask template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="/{{base_href}}/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

One way to streamline the development process is to create a Python script to update the `base hrefs` in all impacted files.